# How do we explain javascript hoisting here?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I wonder why the two code snipped below generate two different results as in reference below the two have to be the same as were are in global scope and placing var would not make a difference.

I was under the impression due to what explained below and the Javascript hoisting the two generate same output, but don't! why?

[What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)

```
console.log(a)
var a = 90;
// undefined
```

vs

```
console.log(a)
a = 90; // no var keyword
// Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Comment: Hoisting is about how *variable declarations* are treated. The second example doesn't contain a variable declaration but an *assignment*. `var a = 42;` and `a = 42;` are two different very operations: https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/aa885eb9965b58e9c54b0a4a9e39e6c1/13cefb8e4b0ab104f85737d86e6d3afdf7c93209 .

Answer (score 2):

When you put `var` keyword, what it does is it moves the `var` part as a declaration on that scope and makes it `undefined`. In the first case, with `var`:

```
console.log(a)
var a = 90;
// undefined
```

Gets rewritten as:

```
var a = undefined;
console.log(a)
a = 90;
// undefined
```

So, you get the `undefined` here, vs. your second case has it the same way, where there's no declaration or key in `window` object named `a`. Hope this is understandable.

The point here is, when you use a `var` keyword, immediately that's defined as `undefined` at the top of the scope before anything.